# How can I get historic flight data by N-number?

Tags: aircraft-registration, flight-schedules, flight-tracking

I'd like to get flight data for the last 10-20 years for an aircraft for which I have an N-number. Basic information-locations and times of arrival and departure.

Is there a free database which will produce these records?

Comment: The US DOT BTS site has this kind of information(not 100% accurate)... but I don't remember the exact area of the site to get the information.

Comment: General aviation, commercial, charter, cargo?

Comment: Related questions: [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/293/62), [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26491/62)

Comment: You might look at [this answer]. It's hard to glean that info from free public databases past a few months. But there are paid databases that have the info if you know how to program and m an api

Answer (score 3):

Some websites offer historic flight records, but they are not free. And they don't go back for decades and are not complete.

If you really must, try the [FAA Registry](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Inquiry.aspx), see if the owner is listed, and get in touch if their contact information is listed.

The FAA only keeps broad records, as [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1241/14897) explains.

Don't get me wrong, but it's like asking where a car has been to for the past 20 years. But I could be mistaken.